# Quarto shows 2 pictures with two duplicate labels in Rstudio

Tags: r, ggplot2, yaml, rstudio, quarto

## Background

This is my code in `.qmd` document in Rstudio. I'm going to write a report using Quarto document in Rstudio.

```
---
title: "Quarto test document"

format: 
  pdf:
    pagesize: "a4"
    number-sections: true
    number-depth: 2
    margin-left: 30mm
    margin-right: 30mm
    execute:
      include: true
      warning: false
      error: false
      freeze: false
    fig-cap-location: bottom
    fig-dpi: 300
    fig-align: center
    fig-format: pdf
---

# Creating picture

\`\`\`{r}
#| label: fig-myplot
#| fig-cap: "This is the label of picture."
#| fig-height: 3
#| fig-width: 4
#| layout-nrow: 1
#| column: page

plot(1:7, abs(-3 : 3))
hist(cars$speed)
\`\`\`
```

## Question

[image]

You can see there are two duplicate same labels except "Figure 1" and "Figure 2". As a matter of fact, I only need "Figure 1: This is the label of picture".

## Methods I've ever tried

#### 1. Adding `#| fig-subcap:`

I added them to R chunk:

```
#| fig-cap: "This is the label of picture."
#| fig-subcap: 
#|  - ""
#|  - ""
#| fig-height: 3
```

[image]

You can see the duplicate labels disappearing. There is only one "Figure 1: This is the label of picture" (See green line). This is my desirable target. However, these labels of `(a)` and `(b)`(see red lines) were at the left-bottom of each picture. In fact, the they should be put on the left-top position of each picture in journal paper. This is not good show.

#### 2. `patchwork` or similar methods

I used `mfrow=c(1,2)`,`patchwork` for ggplot pictures to combine two pictures into one.

[image]
[image]

As you can see, I used `patchwork` to achieve the desired results, but is it possible to directly modify the `YAML` and `#|` section in the quarto document to achieve these effects? After all, when I want to combine the (a) figure using `plot(y~x)` and the (b) figure using `ggplot()` into a single figure, `mfrow=c(x,x)`, `patchwork`, `ggside`, and `ggarrange` become invalid. Using `grid & gridExtra` is of course possible, but the code will look very redundant. I think it is not elegant. I think the best way at the moment is to modify the `#|` content in the YAML and R chunk section, which is the most elegant way.

#### Help me

**1.** In the `### Question` section, if I can keep only "Figure 1:This is the label of picture." without "Figure 2:This is the label of picture." by modifying the `#|` section in  R chunk or YAML components, it will be a great help.

**2.** If I can move the (a) and (b) labels to the top left corner of each figure by modifying the `#|` section in R chunk or YAML component when both (a) and (b) labels exist and keep only one label "Figure 1:This is the label of picture.", it will also be a great help.

Any of the above solutions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way using the layout functionality:

````
---
title: "Quarto test document"
format: 
  pdf:
    pagesize: "a4"
    number-sections: true
    number-depth: 2
    margin-left: 30mm
    margin-right: 30mm
    execute:
      include: true
      warning: false
      error: false
      freeze: false
    fig-cap-location: bottom
    fig-dpi: 300
    fig-align: center
    fig-format: pdf
    
execute: 
  echo: false
---

# Creating picture

::: {layout="[ 0.4, -0.1, 0.4 ]" #fig-myplot}

:::: {#first-column}
```{r}
plot(1:7, abs(-3 : 3))
```
:::

::: {#second-column}
```{r}
hist(cars$speed)
```
:::

This is the label of picture.
::::
````

[image]

Comment: This method did indeed solve my problem, very brilliant. However, these sections `<div>` ::: {#fig-myplot layout="[ 0.5, 0.5 ]"} ::: {#first-column} seem to make the quarto document look very messy. This is a bit of a let down. Can you provide another methods through changing YAML and `#|`? Thank you again.

Comment: I tried every possible combination and this is the only solution that works on quarto 1.3. You can try the prerelease 1.4. maybe they have fixed that. (btw if you use HTML it works if you do not supply sub-fig captions.